# Python - How to clear a integer from a list completely?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Assign list "time" with the following time values.    
time = [15, 27, 32, 36.5, 38.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42, 43.5, 45.5, 47.5, 52.5]
# Remove 1st value(0) from the list
time[0] = []
# Show time
time
[[], 27, 32, 36.5, 38.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42, 43.5, 45.5, 47.5, 52.5]
# Print time 
print(time)
[[], 27, 32, 36.5, 38.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42, 43.5, 45.5, 47.5, 52.5]
```

I'm just following what the tutorial has taught me so far:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`del`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) for this.

```
del time[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness:

```
time.remove(15)
```

But in this case I'd use:

```
del time[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want to do as the example suggests, you'd be doing

```
time[0:1] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

There are literally countless ways to do this.

I prefer `time = time[1:]`